# LinkButtons not working on Chrome on IPhone

Tags: asp.net, iphone, ios, google-chrome

i have created a mobile site in asp.net it is working fine in all phones except one problem with chrome browser in iPhone.

In it there are linkbuttons that are not working.

Any Suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved this issue by adding the below code in the code file...

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.UserAgent != null && (Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("AppleWebKit") > 0))  // added for compatibility issues with chrome 
    {
        this.ClientTarget = "uplevel";
    }

    base.OnPreInit(e);
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendButton.Click += new EventHandler(SendButton_Click);
}
```